# Unable to start activity - ComponentInfo error

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

This are the errors I get when I try to start my app.
Can somebody see what I'm doing wrong?

**The LogCat**

```
11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zimzux.soundapprhk/com.zimzux.soundapprhk.Start}: java.lang.NullPointerException

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at com.zimzux.soundapprhk.Start.onCreate(Start.java:269)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

11-19 14:01:39.993: E/AndroidRuntime(4046):     ... 11 more

11-19 14:01:40.213: I/dalvikvm(4046): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

11-19 14:01:40.213: I/dalvikvm(4046): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

11-19 14:01:40.503: I/dalvikvm(4046): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

11-19 14:01:40.513: I/dalvikvm(4046): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

11-19 14:02:38.883: I/Process(4046): Sending signal. PID: 4046 SIG: 9
```

**Here is my Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zimzux.soundapprhk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Opstart"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zimzux.soundapprhk.OPSTART" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zimzux.soundapprhk.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Here is my XML**

I'm using mostly include, it's easier for me to have an overview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00A2E8"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="SpUsage" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#00A2E8"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/topbanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/topbanner_xml" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/topbannerindstil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/topbanner_indstil_xml" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >  

        <include
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/mainstart_xml" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/afspilmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/afspil_main_xml" />        

        <include
            android:id="@+id/spilstopmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/afspil_spilstop_xml" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/indstil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/indstil_xml" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bund"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bundbanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/bundbanner_xml" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/bundbannerindstil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/bundbanner_indstil_xml" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is my Java**

There is a lot of findViewById's for all the others XML.

```
package com.zimzux.soundapprhk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Start extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp1;
    MediaPlayer mp2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.start_xml);


        final LinearLayout top = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.top);
        final LinearLayout bund = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bund);
        final LinearLayout topbannerafspil = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.topbanner);
        final LinearLayout bundbannerafspil = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bundbanner);
        final LinearLayout start = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.start);
        final LinearLayout afspil = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.afspilmain);
        final LinearLayout spilstop = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.spilstopmain);
        final LinearLayout indstil = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.indstil);
        final LinearLayout topbannerindstil = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.topbannerindstil);
        final LinearLayout bundbannerindstil = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bundbannerindstil);

        ImageView btnstart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
        ImageView btnindstil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnindstil);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        TextView textnowpl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textnowpl);

        Button btnscor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnscor);
        Button btntimeout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btntimeout);
        Button btnudvisning = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnudvisning);
        Button btnstraffe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstraffe);
        Button btnindlob = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnindlob);
        Button btnopvarmning = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnopvarmning);
        Button btnhalvleg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnhalvleg);
        Button btnnextsong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnextsong);
        Button btnspilstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnspilstop);

        Button btnbasic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnbasic);
        Button btnspilswitchstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnspilswitchstop);
        Button btnfadeud = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfadeud);
        Button btnstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstop);

        Button spilstop1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop1);
        Button spilstop2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop2);
        Button spilstop3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop3);
        Button spilstop4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop4);
        Button spilstop5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop5);
        Button spilstop6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop6);
        Button spilstop7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop7);
        Button spilstop8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop8);
        Button spilstop9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop9);
        Button spilstop10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop10);
        Button spilstop11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop11);
        Button spilstop12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop12);
        Button spilstop13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop13);
        Button spilstop14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop14);
        Button spilstop15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop15);
        Button spilstop16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spilstop16);




        top.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        topbannerafspil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        topbannerindstil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bund.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bundbannerafspil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bundbannerindstil.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        afspil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spilstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        indstil.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        btnstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                topbannerafspil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bundbannerafspil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                afspil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spilstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                indstil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                topbannerindstil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bundbannerindstil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bund.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }});

        btnindstil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                topbannerafspil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bundbannerafspil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                afspil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                spilstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                indstil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                topbannerindstil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bundbannerindstil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bund.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }});

        btnbasic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){


                afspil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spilstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }});

        btnspilswitchstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){


                afspil.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                spilstop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }});
}}
```

Comment: what is `Line 269` in `Start.java`

Comment: that is why you declare and initialize class-variables at the beginning of your class. So you never get null inside your methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs on line 269?
I am unable to identify what line that is as you provide 135 lines in your start activity.

My guess, however, is that your findViewById method is looking for a resource that doesn't exist. check that your xml fine contains all of the buttons/linear layouts/image views etc etc that you are referencing in the activity.

If not that then you need to declare your buttons etc as class variables, then initialize them in the on create method, allowing access in further methods and inner classes.

Comment: It provides a potential solution to the problem, no?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the code,but the line num is not correct, the cause of this error is definitely clear,findViewById not find the view of the id,please recheck your code